# On "Redundant 'static' modifier" warning

Tags: java

Within `public interface Constants` i declared

```
static final boolean        TREAT_AS_SOURCE     = true
```

and got a message that it is a redundantly declared as `static`.

Help me understand why that is?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

All field members declared in an interface are by default `public`, `static` and `final`, therefore, it is redundant to say it again.

Answer (score 5):

Fields in an interface are `public, static and final` by default.